# How to resolve Flutter Agora RTC showing error code 110

Tags: android, flutter, agora.io

Greetings to fellow developers,

I am working on a project where I have to display a functional video call between two users. For reference, I have been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9ngriCV0J0
which has given a step-by-step explanation for establishing a video call between two users.

However, the only issue is that the video is having a Firebase backend. Hence, whenever a caller creates a call model with sender and recipient Ids, the recipient immediately receives the same data and a call is established. Whereas, I am using Node/Express backend (manual API calls for updating fetching data) which makes it extremely difficult to receive the required call data from the receiver's end as soon as the caller sends it to the backend. Also, it will be inefficient to listen for fetching the call data the whole time.

I will be very grateful to all of you if you can help me find a working approach so that the receiver can fetch the required call data as soon as the caller creates it in the backend for establishing a video call from separate devices.

Here's my code
https://pastebin.com/AurJnG27

```
/***pubspec.yaml dependencies***/

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  provider: ^4.3.3
  socket_io_client: ^0.9.9
  permission_handler: ^3.0.0
  agora_rtc_engine: ^1.0.8
      
/***pubspec.yaml dependencies***/
```

Please let me know if any further information is required from my side. Any feedback for code improvisation (if you feel like it) is also very appreciated.

Comment: if you guys got the solution can you help me out. I'm on the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because of an incorrect or expired token that you might be using. Firstly, I will suggest shifting to the latest version of the Agora SDK and then build your application.
Now, if you're just testing out the platform then from your Agora dashboard you can go ahead and generate a new App ID and select the testing mode which will disable token. So in your `joinChannel()` method you can pass `null` for the token value.

But if your application is live or is in production then go ahead and select the secured mode from your Agora dashboard. Then you will have to generate a token server from a deployed server, you can read more about it [here](https://meherdeept.medium.com/connecting-to-agora-with-tokens-flutter-ea82a97f57bc).

Now, coming to the Firebase part. You can actually make this process much simpler by using the Agora RTM SDK. Which allows you to send messages, through this you can send peer message about the call details and hence refer it while making a call. You can have a look at this blog which shows how you can use the RTM SDK to do the same: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-your-own-audio-streaming-application-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/

If you're interested you can have a look at this sample code given [here](https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-group-calling/tree/tokens) which will help you setup a proper video calling application.

I will also recommend you to join the [Agora Slack Channel](https://agoraio.slack.com/) where you can get help from other Agora developers.

Comment: Thanks meherdeep this worked, we were actually able to resolve it ourselves while we went over the documentation ourselves